# How to create a collection of interfaces that have a generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to make a framework that can be extended by the implementer. at a high level there will be a several different implementations of a base object, and all such instances of those different implementations will need to be processed together. the most versatile and elegant solution for the implementer would seem to be generic typing, but putting them together in a collection is tripping me up.

I've tried using a class or and interface that has a generic type, and then the implementation fixes it, but i cant build a list. for example

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GenericsMixingExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new Container();
            container.Wrappers.Add(new IntWrapper { Value = 5 });
            container.Wrappers.Add(new IntWrapper { Value = 5 });
            container.Wrappers.Add(new StringWrapper { Value = "value" });
            container.Wrappers.ForEach((e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Value.ToString()); });
        }
    }

    interface ValueWrapper<T>
    {
        T Value { get; set; }
    }

    class IntWrapper : ValueWrapper<int>
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    class StringWrapper : ValueWrapper<string>
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    interface IContainer
    {
        List<ValueWrapper> Wrappers { get; set; }
    }

    class Container : IContainer
    {
        public List<ValueWrapper> Wrappers { get; set; }
        public Container()
        {
            Wrappers = new List<ValueWrapper>();
        }
    }
}
```

but that gives the error `Using the generic type 'ValueWrapper<T>' requires 1 type arguments` when i try to define the list

i thought maybe an abstract class that returns `object` and then overriding the type would work:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace objectBased
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new Container();
            container.Wrappers.Add(new IntWrapper { Value = 5 });
            container.Wrappers.Add(new IntWrapper { Value = 5 });
            container.Wrappers.Add(new StringWrapper { Value = "value" });
            container.Wrappers.ForEach((e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Value.ToString()); });
        }
    }

    abstract class IValueWrapper
    {
        public virtual object Value { get; set; }
    }

    class IntWrapper : IValueWrapper
    {
        private int _value;
        public override object Value {
            get { return _value; }
            set { _value = Convert.ToInt32(value); }
        }
    }

    class StringWrapper : IValueWrapper
    {
        private string _value;
        public override object Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set { _value = (value as string); }
        }
    }

    interface IContainer
    {
        List<IValueWrapper> Wrappers { get; set; }
    }

    class Container : IContainer
    {
        public List<IValueWrapper> Wrappers { get; set; }
        public Container()
        {
            Wrappers = new List<IValueWrapper>();
        }
    }
}
```

but this falls apart when i try to add more complexity:

```cs
abstract class IValueWrapper
    {
        public virtual object Value { get; set; }
        public abstract void Randomize();
        public abstract object MixValues(object otherValue);
    }

    class IntWrapper : IValueWrapper
    {
        public static int MAX_RANDOM = 100;
        private int _value;
        public override object Value {
            get { return _value; }
            set { _value = Convert.ToInt32(value); }
        }
        public override void Randomize()
        {
            Random rng = new Random();
            Value = rng.Next(0, MAX_RANDOM);
        }
        public override int MixValues(int otherValue)
        {
            int smaller = Math.Min(otherValue, Value);
            int larger = Math.Min(otherValue, Value);
            return smaller - (larger - smaller) / 2;
        }
    }
```

In the above block MixValues cannot override the abstract because the return type is different, the input type is different, and Value isn't an int. The abstract class method looks like it requires tons of casting that I'm not overly interested in.

As a stretch goal I would like to be able to have methods like mix be static methods that return a new instance of the class

```cs
public static IntWrapper MixValues()
{
    return new IntWrapper() //...etc
}
```

but i can live without that if its necessarily difficult

so is there any way i can make that list of generically typed parent objects?

Comment: A factory method might be your best bet. You can use a dictionary to switch between the types like so: Dictionary<MyEnum, Class1> mapper = new Dictionary<MyEnum, Class1>(); Then add the different types to your dict like: mapper.Add(MyEnum.1, new Class1()); Ex: https://code-maze.com/factory-method/

Comment: "all such instances of those different implementations will need to be processed together." Can you elaborate? What does "processed" mean? What do these objects have in common that makes you want to put them all in the same list?

Comment: its for a genetic algorithm project. processing in this case means breeding and mutating. i was originally thinking something like how XNA processes components in the update cycle 
```
List<IUpdatable> components = new List<IUpdatable>();
components.foreach(c => c.Update(time.now()))
```
but maybe im thinking of this wrong. I wanted to make a genome a collection of genes,  but i think maybe making the genome a model that contains specific assortments of genes and implements certain genome interface functions would be good enough. i'll fiddle with that.

Comment: the question remains in the abstract though, i can make a collection of parent types and fill it which children normally, is there a way to do that if the parent has a generic type that the child fills?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do with the processing, but perhaps you could do something like this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GenericsMixingExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new Container();
            container.Wrappers.Add(new IntProcessor { Value = 5 });
            container.Wrappers.Add(new IntProcessor { Value = 5 });
            container.Wrappers.Add(new StringProcessor { Value = "value" });
            container.Wrappers.ForEach((e) => { e.Process(); });
        }
    }

    interface IProcessor
    {
        void Process();
    }

    class IntProcessor : IProcessor
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }

        public void Process()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processing: " + Value);
        }
    }

    class StringProcessor : IProcessor
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public void Process()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processing: " + Value);
        }
    }

    interface IContainer
    {
        List<IProcessor> Wrappers
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    class Container : IContainer
    {
        public List<IProcessor> Wrappers
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That gets rid of the ability to read the field from the list without some casting... i'd have to think on it for a bit to decide if i actually need those values readable, but i think there's still a general C# question here though: i can make a collection of parent types and fill it which children normally, is there a way to do that if the parent has a generic type that the child fills?